# How to use httplib as the useragent in Python

Tags: python, http

How can I add a useragent to the following script?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
saudidos = True
while saudidos:
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1")
    conn.request("GET", "/");
```

Comment: You aren't using the request library.

Comment: Did you try and [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.request) yet? The `connection.request()` method takes headers to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have example how to send headers:

```
 Example: Using the httplib module to post data

# File: httplib-example-2.py

import httplib

USER_AGENT = "httplib-example-2.py"

def post(host, path, data, type=None):

    http = httplib.HTTP(host)

    # write header
    http.putrequest("PUT", path)
    http.putheader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
    http.putheader("Host", host)
    if type:
        http.putheader("Content-Type", type)
    http.putheader("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    http.endheaders()

    # write body
    http.send(data)

    # get response
    errcode, errmsg, headers = http.getreply()

    if errcode != 200:
        raise Error(errcode, errmsg, headers)

    file = http.getfile()
    return file.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    post("www.spam.egg", "/bacon.htm", "a piece of data", "text/plain")
```

From: http://effbot.org/librarybook/httplib.htm

Answer (score 1):

A bit late response but I wanted to add to the previous response for anyone who might find this page. The short answer is with the request method of an instance of `HTTPConnection`. It should be declared as a dictionary. Here's a less verbose example than above:

```
headers = {'foo': 'bar'}

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('hostname')
connection.request('GET', headers)
```

You could also add the following to see your response in more detail:

```
response = connection.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason  # this is python 2 syntax
data = response.read()
print data
```

I suggest using https://requestb.in/ to see what you're sending!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using httplib2 you should use headers dict to perform your request in the same way the requests module does:

```
from httplib2 import Http
http = Http()
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
url = "https://www.google.com"
_, content = http.request(url, "GET", headers=headers)
```